# Paper.js: Why by scaling an image becomes blurred?

Tags: paperjs

Paper.js: Why by scaling an image becomes blurred?
Code

```
            paper.setup(canvasDOMElement);
            var raster = new paper.Raster(image2);
            // raster.size = new paper.Size(800, 600);
            raster.scale(0.05, {x:110, y:110});
            // raster.position = paper.view.center;
            paper.view.draw();
```

[image]

The image is 3000x2500 px and is blurred at borders and the image itself. If I don't use the scale the image is clear.

Well I've made an animation like this:

```
        onAppear = function(){
            paper.setup(canvasDOMElement);
            var raster = new paper.Raster(image2);
            // raster.size = new paper.Size(800, 600);
            // raster.scale(1, {x:110, y:110});
            // raster.position = paper.view.center;
            var scale = 1;
            paper.view.onFrame = function(event) {
                // On each frame, rotate the path by 3 degrees:
                scale -= 0.0001;
                raster.scale(scale, {x:110, y:110});
            }
            paper.view.draw();
        }
```

This is kind of weird as the scale is applied one over the other and therefore has an exponential curve, which is not what I thought. So a better way is:

```
        onAppear = function(){
            paper.setup(canvasDOMElement);
            var raster = new paper.Raster(image2);
            // raster.size = new paper.Size(800, 600);
            // raster.scale(1, {x:110, y:110});
            // raster.position = paper.view.center;
            var scale = 1;
            paper.view.onFrame = function(event) {
                // On each frame, rotate the path by 3 degrees:
                raster.scale(0.99, {x:110, y:110});
            }
            paper.view.draw();
        }
```

In this way the image is re-scaling on each frame to 0.99. Even so, after 200 iterations the image is becoming very very blurred.

Comment: Blurred how? If you're scaling 800x600 to 0.05 it's original size, that's 40x30px. You are going to lose _a lot_ of image data here.

Comment: just updated with an image (my photo is 3000x2500px)

Comment: fixed! the canvas was scaling itself therefore the images were blurred.

Comment: Good to know you fixed it. You might want to answer this question yourself and mark it as accepted to "close" your question and provide good reference for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real real problem is explained here: http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.1/apiviewer/index.html#qx.ui.embed.Canvas

**syncDimension = true!**

```
var canvas = new qx.ui.embed.Canvas().set({
  syncDimension: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the main source of the problem is that I've not been aware about the **difference between the canvas.style.height and canvas.height**:

Both of them changes the height of the canvas but

the **canvas.style.height** changes the scale, therefore I've blurred images

and the **canvas.height** keeps the same scale so no blurred images.

**For qooxdoo users:**

```
var canvas = new qx.ui.embed.Canvas().set({});
// changing the height on canvas like this:
canvas.setHeight(900)
// will set the canvas.style.height
// which will become blurred

// therefore you must do:
var canvasDOMElement = canvas.getContentElement().getDomElement();
canvasDOMElement.height = 900;
// this will resize your canvas without scaling it.
```